# Snowflake invalid materialized view definition

Tags: materialized-views, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When running in Snowflake the following command:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_CUSTOMER_PREFERENCE as select * from V_CUSTOMER_PREFERENCE;
```

I get the following error:

> SQL compilation error: error line {0} at position {1} Invalid materialized view definition. More than one table referenced in the view definition

`V_CUSTOMER_PREFERENCE` is an existing and functioning view (it can be queried separately), that joins information from different tables. I get the same error when I put the original query instead of the view, it's just a long and complicated SQL query.

What can be the problem with the query in the view? I cannot understand it from the error description and I didn't find related restrictions in https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/views-materialized.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A materialized view can query only a single table. You can see the list of limitations for working with materialized views here:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/views-materialized.html#limitations-on-creating-materialized-views

Comment: So there's no effective way to materialize complex views that include more than few tables joins.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct:  Unlike other databases, MVIEWS in Snowflake are a very targeted and simplified feature.  They have the following use cases:

- Provide Alternative Clustering for tables with multiple access paths.
- Provide Project/Restrict on high use columns/rows.
- Provide Pre-aggregation for high frequency queries and sub-queries.